# Fabry Perot vs Michelson interferometer

Tags: interferometry

Why are the fringes obtained with Fabry Perot interferometer are sharper than that obtained by Michelson interferometer?

Comment: Are they?  Please explain what you mean.

Comment: @garyp By sharper I mean, the ratio of maximum intensity (bright fringe) to minimum intensity (dark fringe) is greater in Fabry Perot interferometer compared to Michelson.

Comment: The "dark" fringe in a Fabry-Perot can be very "bright", and the "dark" fringe in a Michaelson can be zero.   So I'm still not sure what you are getting at.